# Initialize a 2D-array at declarationtime in the C programming language

Tags: c, arrays

How do I initialize a 2D array with 0s when I declare it?

`double myArray[3][12] = ?`

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
double myArray[3][12] = {0};
```

or, if you want to avoid the gcc warning "missing braces around initializer" (the warning appears with `-Wall` or, more specifically `-Wmissing-braces`)

```
double myArray[3][12] = {{0}};
```

Comment: If you use the paragraph code blocks (four spaces at the beginning of line) you get syntax hightlighting, which you don't if you use inline blocks (backticks).

Comment: Is this syntax [C99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C99) or later?

Comment: @Danijel: the `{0}` initializer has been valid since C89 (the 1st standardization). Don't know about before that.

Answer (score 22):

If you want to initialize with zeroes, you do the following:

```
double myArray[3][12] = { 0 };
```

If you want to fill in actual values, you can nest the braces:

```
double myArray[3][3] = { { 0.1, 0.2, 0.3 }, { 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 }, { 2.1, 2.2, 2.3 } };
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out how to initialize everything ... but why did you shorten the array? :P

Comment: I shortened the array because I didn't want to type twelve sets of numbers.

Comment: You might consider using a non-square array for the second example so it's clear which dimension is the inner and which is the outer

Comment: It does not work for me, I have "error: variable-sized object may not be initialized"

Answer (score 13):

The memory layout may be relevant (e.g., for serialization).

```
myArray[3][2] = { { 0.1, 0.2 }, { 1.1, 1.2 }, { 2.1, 2.2 } };
```

**The first index is the row index is the slowest index.** This is known as C order as opposed to F (Fortran) order.

Answer (score 10):

pmg's method is correct, however, note that

```
double myArray[3][12] = {{}};
```

will give the same result.

Additionally, keep in mind that

```
double myArray[3][12] = {{some_number}};
```

will only work as you expect it when some_number is zero.

For example, if I were to say

```
double myArray[2][3] = {{3.1}};
```

the array would not be full of 3.1's, instead it will be

```
3.1  0.0  0.0
0.0  0.0  0.0
```

(the first element is the only one set to the specified value, the rest are set to zero)

This [question (c initialization of a normal array with one default value)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value) has more information

Comment: The empty initializer is invalid C (I believe it is valid C++).

Comment: @pmg or @codyschafer, can anyone point me to the standard where either of your arguments is stated please? initialization using `={ }`  appears to work in both gcc and g++, but I don't know whether its correct.

Comment: @GrimFandango: the [C11 syntax for initialization](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.7.9) does not allow *empty initializer* (same for [C99](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.7.8)). If you're using gcc, try `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic ...` otherwise `gcc ...` is the same as `gcc -std=gnu11 ...`

Comment: @GrimFandango: compare C11 6.7.9 (link in my previous comment) with C++14 8.5.1 (sorry, no link)

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
double myArray[3][12] = { 0 };
```

or

```
double myArray[3][12];
memset(myArray, 0, sizeof(double) * 3 * 12);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it will be

```
double myArray[3][12] = {0}
```

Answer (score 0):

pmg's method works best as it works on the concept that if u initialise any array partially, rest of them get the default value of zero. else, u can declare the array as a global variable and when not initialised, the array elements will automatically be set to the default value (depending on compilers) zero.