# Initialize array of strings with \0

Tags: c, arrays, string, initialization

I would like to initialize an array of strings with \0.
Is it right to do it like this?

```
char first[1024][1024] = {'\0'};
```

Comment: in this way, your array will be totally zeroed.

Comment: You can make it simpler and just use `{0}`.

Comment: @Arpit: I'm not seeing a `static`, so I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: it was full of rubbish before initialization :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Initialize a 2D-array at declarationtime in the C programming language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688741/initialize-a-2d-array-at-declarationtime-in-the-c-programming-language)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a 2d array is better to use:

```
char first[1024][1024] = {{'\0'},{'\0'}};
```

or better yet (as suggested by @haccks):

```
char first[1024][1024] = {{'\0'}};
```

in order to avoid warnings.

Comment: @haccks, sorry for rollback your edit, but gcc gives a warning using `{'\0'}`

Comment: @AlterMann; Interesting!

Comment: @haccks, edited, you are right, compiles without warning and I was trying `char first[1024][1024] = {'\0'};`

Answer (score -1):

If it is a static array, say, a global array, you do not need to do any initialization and the values of the array are set to 0 by default.

Comment: It cannot be judged the array in the question is static or not from the expression of the question, so why you are sure that it is not a static array? @lgor