# global 2d array in C

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array

I tried initialising a 2D global array in C like this `int array[100][100] = {{500}};`  But then when I access the array elements from my function, the array elements show up as zero instead of 500. How to fix this?

Comment: It only fills with zeroes. To specify other, you must specify each.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Initialize a 2D-array at declarationtime in the C programming language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688741/initialize-a-2d-array-at-declarationtime-in-the-c-programming-language)

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson how do I make all elements 500 then?

Comment: ... by specifying them all individually. (Or, more tractably, programmatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int array[100][100] = {{500}};
```

initializes only `array[0][0]` to `500`. The rest of array elements are initialized to `0`.

Example:

```
int main(void)
{
    int array[10][10] = {{500}};

    for(size_t row = 0; row < 10; row++)
    {
        for(size_t col = 0; col < 10; col++)
            printf("%4d", array[row][col]); 
    printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
 500   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

> how would i make all the elements 500 in the global array?

```
int array[100][100] =   {
/*line 1  */    {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, },
 /* 100 lines */
 /* ... */
/*line 100  */  {500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, 500, },};
```

Comment: how would i make all the elements 500 in the global array?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts The same way you display the array ? With two for ?

Comment: @Tom's but would that work for a global variable array?

Comment: @ferocioussprouts yes ? Why would this doesn't work ? Try it and if it doesn't work, update your question with your code.

Comment: Please use a loop instead.

Comment: @HardcoreGamer show me the way of using loops in the static storage duration array definition. If you know one and show the working example, I will owe you 100 bucks

Comment: @0___________ Apparently I was wrong, OP specifically asked for initializing, you keep your 100 : )