# What's the proper way to declare and initialize a (large) two dimensional object array in c++?

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, initialization, declaration

I need to create a large two dimensional array of objects. I've read some related questions on this site and others regarding multi_array, matrix, vector, etc, but haven't been able to put it together. If you recommend using one of those, please go ahead and translate the code below.

Some considerations:

- The array is somewhat large (1300 x 1372).
- I might be working with more than one of these at a time.
- I'll have to pass it to a function at some point.
- Speed is a large factor.

The two approaches that I thought of were:

```
Pixel pixelArray[1300][1372];
for(int i=0; i<1300; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<1372; j++) {
        pixelArray[i][j].setOn(true);
        ...
    }
}
```

and

```
Pixel* pixelArray[1300][1372];
for(int i=0; i<1300; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<1372; j++) {
        pixelArray[i][j] = new Pixel();
        pixelArray[i][j]->setOn(true);
        ...
    }
}
```

What's the right approach/syntax here?

**Edit:**

Several answers have assumed `Pixel` is small - I left out details about `Pixel` for convenience, but it's not small/trivial. It has ~20 data members and ~16 member functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first approach allocates everything on stack, which is otherwise fine, but leads to stack overflow when you try to allocate too much stack. The limit is usually around 8 megabytes on modern OSes, so that allocating arrays of 1300 * 1372 elements on stack is not an option.

Your second approach allocates 1300 * 1372 elements on heap, which is a tremendous load for the allocator, which holds multiple linked lists to chunks of allocted and free memory. Also a bad idea, especially since Pixel seems to be rather small.

What I would do is this:

```
Pixel* pixelArray = new Pixel[1300 * 1372];
for(int i=0; i<1300; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<1372; j++) {
        pixelArray[i * 1372 + j].setOn(true);
        ...
    }
}
```

This way you allocate one large chunk of memory on heap. Stack is happy and so is the heap allocator.

Comment: I would combine the flat array with a sensible default constructor, so you might be able to get away without any explicit initialization loop.

Comment: @antti I'm assuming `Pixel* pixelArray = new pixelArray[1300 * 1372];` should be `Pixel* pixelArray = new Pixel[1300 * 1372];`

Comment: @allen, in case of obvious edits, you can just press 'edit' link below the answer and make changes yourself, they'll apply as soon as will be peer reviewed. You can do it to everything on the site.

Comment: ended up using this solution because it's simple, fast, and clear (as to what's happening and what needs to be done). thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass it to a function, I'd vote against using simple arrays. Consider:

```
void doWork(Pixel array[][]);
```

This does not contain any size information. You could pass the size info via separate arguments, but I'd rather use something like std::vector<Pixel>. Of course, this requires that you define an addressing convention (row-major or column-major).

An alternative is std::vector<std::vector<Pixel> >, where each level of vectors is one array dimension. Advantage: The double subscript like in pixelArray[x][y] works, but the creation of such a structure is tedious, copying is more expensive because it happens per contained vector instance instead of with a simple memcpy, and the vectors contained in the top-level vector must not necessarily have the same size.

These are basically your options using the Standard Library. The right solution would be something like std::vector with two dimensions. Numerical libraries and image manipulation libraries come to mind, but  matrix and image classes are most likely limited to primitive data types in their elements.

EDIT: Forgot to make it clear that everything above is only arguments. In the end, your personal taste and the context will have to be taken into account. If you're on your own in the project, vector plus defined and documented addressing convention should be good enough. But if you're in a team, and it's likely that someone will disregard the documented convention, the cascaded vector-in-vector structure is probably better because the tedious parts can be implemented by helper functions.

Comment: I would like `vector<vector<Pixel> >` if not for all the babysitting it seems like I would have to do to make it behave (`operator=`, `operator&`, `operator=`, etc) and act efficiently (don't copy/call deconstructor all the time!).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how complicated your Pixel data type is, but maybe something like this will work for you?:

std::fill(array, array+100, 42); // sets every value in the array to 42

Reference:
[Initialization of a normal array with one default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)

Comment: My primary concern was program efficiency as opposed to programming efficiency. But even so I think if I did this then I'd have to define `operator=` type functions for `Pixel` and then I might as well be using `vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out Boost's Generic Image Library.

```
gray8_image_t pixelArray;
pixelArray.recreate(1300,1372);
for(gray8_image_t::iterator pIt = pixelArray.begin(); pIt != pixelArray.end(); pIt++) {
    *pIt = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While I wouldn't necessarily make this a struct, this demonstrates how I would approach storing and accessing the data.  If Pixel is rather large, you may want to use a std::deque instead.

```
struct Pixel2D {
  Pixel2D (size_t rsz_, size_t csz_) : data(rsz_*csz_), rsz(rsz_), csz(csz_) {
    for (size_t r = 0; r < rsz; r++)
    for (size_t c = 0; c < csz; c++)
      at(r, c).setOn(true);
  }
  Pixel &at(size_t row, size_t col) {return data.at(row*csz+col);}
  std::vector<Pixel> data;
  size_t rsz;
  size_t csz;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

My personal peference would be to use std::vector

```
typedef  std::vector<Pixel>       PixelRow;
typedef  std::vector<PixelRow>    PixelMatrix;

PixelMatrix   pixelArray(1300, PixelRow(1372, Pixel(true)));
      //                 ^^^^           ^^^^  ^^^^^^^^^^^
      //                 Size 1         Size 2   default Value
```