# allocating array pointer c++ equivalent code

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm modifying some code I found to be inside a C++ object. Message is a c++ class.

The original line of code looks like this:

```
unsigned char fifoQueue[256 * sizeof(Message)] = {0};
```

Since I'm putting it into an object, I'm doing this:

```
///in header
unsigned char fifoQueue;

///in object initializer
fifoQueue = new unsigned char[256 * sizeof(Message)];
```

Somehow I don't think that is correct. What's the correct implementation to get the same result?   I'm just a bit cloudy about how this works - In the given example fifoQueue is a pointer to a memory location, correct?  Should my object have the fifoQueue instance variable as a pointer to a "Message" array, instead?

Thanks!

///////
Okay, I'm adding some information here that is relevant to the way this is being used. Sorry for not including this before.

There is a method that accesses this value as a pointer and increments it based on a read/write location.  So I need the new initializer such that this method works correctly.

```
Message* Fifo::getMessageToWrite(){

    Message* base = (Message*)fifoQueue;
    return new(base + (fifoWritePtr & 255)) Message();

}
```

Comment: Check [C/C++ initialization of a normal array with one default value](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1065774/1168156).

Comment: This looks like an XY problem, so there's probably a much better solution, but for now try `std::vector<char> fifoQueue` and initialize it with `fifoQueue(256 * sizeof(int))`.

Comment: Why don't you like the original?

Comment: I made an edit --- int has been replaced by Message, since really its an array of objects....

Comment: Christian- I'd like it to be an instance variable.  So I believe I need to declare the instance variable in the header and then initialize it in the initializer.  I don't think I can do that directly in the header, can i?

Comment: In my understanding yes, if you know the array size, you can declare it on the stack. You can declare the array like `Message fifoQueue[256]` and if you need a pointer to a specific element `return &fifoQueue[x]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the looks of it, you want to pass objects of type `Message` through a queue. For this, the proper C++ mechanism is to use `std::queue<Message>`: it will grow to an appropriate size when pushing new messages into the queue. Unlike the `std::vector<T>` proposed in other answers, this actually uses a `std::deque<Message>` under the hood (you can use a `std::deque<Message>` directly but if you want a queue just use a queue).

The advantage of using a `std::queue<Message>` is that the object inside this queue stays put while they keep being shuffled around in a `std::vector<Message>`: while `std::vector<T>` only supports efficient (i.e. O(1)) addition/removal at the back as is e.g. used for a stack (LIFO), `std::deque<T>` supports efficient addition/removal at both ends as is needed for a queue (FIFO). I think the complexity of adding/removing to a `std::deque<T>` is only amortized constant but this is still better than linear complexity you'd get with a `std::vector<T>` when using it as a FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

The second version declares an `unsigned char` and tries to assign a `unsigned char*` to it. This is not going to work and even so it is not clear to me why you would allocate enough space for 256 `intS` and assign them to a `unsigned char*` unless you are doing something very low level. A `std::vector` is probably the better choice anyway.

Comment: Sorry, I've made an edit here to reflect the problem better.  Instead of Int, the fifoQueue is for storing an object called Message.

Comment: @olynoise And you are sure that the code accessing `fifoQueue` deals with alignment, padding and endianess? Otherwise I don't see why you are using a pointer to `unsigned char`?

Comment: @olynoise You maybe should not refactor this without knowing what you are doing. It looks dangerous.

Comment: @olynoise By reading and writing code (that is not over your head) and with a good book.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake: [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) is more preferable way instead of manual dynamic memory allocation (plain-old pointers).

```
#include <vector>
...
std::vector<char> fifoQueue(256);
```