# fastest way to set a 2-dim array of double all to -1?

Tags: c++, c, arrays

What is the fastest way to set a 2-dim array of double,such as double x[N][N] all to -1?

I tried to use memset, but failed. Any good idea?

Comment: memset is the fastest way. What exactly did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: try memset_pattern (http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/memset_pattern/)

Comment: you have to use a loop.

Comment: Show us what you tried? Maybe it's just a rookie mistake you glossed over.

Comment: @Vicky: `memset` fills bytes, not double-sized values. In C++, there's `std::fill`, but the OP doesn't seem know which language he's using.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: make that an answer, please.

Comment: @EricLeschinski et. al This question is not a duplicate of the suggested question. The suggested question does explicitly state that the element type is `double` and this question does. In particular fill array with `-1.0`. I think 2-dim part is less interesting.

Answer (score 2):

Use: [std::fill_n](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/fill_n/) from `algorithm`

```
std::fill_n(*array, sizeof(array) / sizeof (**array), -1 );
```

Example:

```
double array[10][10];
std::fill_n( *array, sizeof(array) / sizeof (**array), -1.0 );

//Display Matrix
for(auto i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    for(auto j=0;j<10;j++)
        cout<<array[i][j]<< " ";    
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour all the explanation is contained in the linked reference.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour fastest depends on the implementation, data size and phase of the moon. Only a benchmark can tell. Performance doesn't matter until a profiler says otherwise.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: `memset` doesn't perform the operation in question; since this solution does, it is obviously superior.  “Fastest” doesn’t enter into it.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour Since `memset` takes infinite time to solve the problem while this approach doesn't, it is obviously faster than `memset`.

Comment: @StephenCanon Got it, I misread the answer to a previous thread, rereading that thread I see what you are saying.

Answer (score 1):

Also you can set directly

```
    double x[4][4] = {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1}
```

if the array index is small.

Comment: Look, what if I have array[1000][1000]? It's not a good answer.

Comment: It is even worse. It set the first element to -1 and the rest to 0.

Comment: pls go to this link [linkd]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value[link]

Comment: It just confirmed that your answer is bad.

Comment: hey am just telling you to refer to find a solution, not to prove my answer is optimized....

Comment: I know what your answer is wrong and I know how to do that stuff...

Comment: And I stated, what your answer is wrong because someone, who is just beginner in programming may think, that it is good and useful, so I help em not to waste time.

Answer (score 1):

A simple loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    #define N 5
    double x[N][N];
    size_t i, n = sizeof(x) / sizeof(double);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        x[0][i] = -1.0;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf("%zu) %f\n", i, x[0][i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// create constants
const int rows = 10;
const int columns = 10;

// declare a 2D array
double myArray [rows][columns];

// run a double loop to fill up the array
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) 
    for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++)
        myArray[rows][columns] = -1.0;

// print out the results
for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < columns; k++)
        cout << myArray[rows][columns];

    cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::array` and its `fill` method:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  const std::size_t N=4
  std::array<double, N*N> arr; // better to keep the memory 1D and access 2D!
  arr.fill(-1.);
  for(auto element : arr)
    std::cout << element << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using C++ containers you can use the fill method

```
array<array<double, 1024>, 1024> matrix;

matrix.fill(-1.0);
```

if, for some reason, you have to stick with C-style arrays you can initialize the first row manually and then memcpy to the other rows. This works regardless if you have defined it as static array or allocated row by row.

```
const int rows = 1024;
const int cols = 1024;
double matrix[rows][cols]

for ( int i=0; i<cols; ++i)
{ 
    matrix[0][cols] = -1.0;
}
for ( int r=1; r<rows; ++r)
{
    // use the previous row as source to have it cache friendly for large matrices
    memcpy(&(void*)(matrix[row][0]), &(void*)(matrix[row-1][0]), cols*sizeof(double));
}
```

But I rather would try to move from C style arrays to the C++ containers than doing that kind of stunt.

Answer (score 0):

`memset` shouldn't be used here because it is based on `void *`. So all bytes in are the same. `(float)` `-1` is `0xbf800000` (`double` 0xbff0000000000000) so not all bytes are the same...

I would use manual filling:

```
const int m = 1024;
const int n = 1024;
double arr[m][n];
for (size_t i = 0; i < m*n; i++)
    arr[i] = -1;
```

Matrix is like array in memory, so better to have 1 loop, it slightly faster.

Or you can use this:
`std::fill_n(arr, m*n, -1);`

Not sure which one is faster, but both looks similar. So probably you'll need to make small test to find it out, but as far as I know people usually use one or another. And another thing first one is more `C` on some compiler it won't work and second is real `C++` it and never works on `C`. So you should choose by the programming language I think :)