# Assigning values to multiple declarations on same line

Tags: c++

I am creating variables as such

```
std::string str1,str2,str3,str4 = "Default";
```

however the variables do not have the Default value. How can I assign values to variables created this way

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`str4` will have the value you're looking for.  You just didn't initialize the others.  Use:

```
std::string str1 = "Default", str2 = "Default", str3 = "Default", str4 = "Default";
```

Or, probably better:

```
std::string str1 = "Default";
std::string str2 = "Default";
std::string str3 = "Default";
std::string str4 = "Default";
```

If you're concerned about doing so much typing, you can use assignment instead of initialization:

```
std::string str1, str2, str3, str4;
str1 = str2 = str3 = str4 = "Default";
```

But that's got different semantics and is (IMHO) a bit hinky.

Comment: I'd change "probably" to "actually"

Comment: I agree, but that's a value judgement. =)

Answer (score 4):

Generally when you have variable names with numbers in them, an array will be better suited. This gives you the added benefit of using `std::fill_n` as well

```
#include <algorithm>

std::string str[4];
std::fill_n( str, 4, "Default" ); // from link provided by Smac89
// str[0], str[1], str[2], str[3] all set to "Default"
```

Comment: Actually, this only initialises the first string to "Default". The rest are not initialised

Comment: @Smac89 `int a[100] = {0};` initializes all a to 0. Is it different with classes?

Comment: [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)

Answer (score 2):

How about chaining?

```
std::string str1, str2, str3, str4;
str1 = str2 = str3 = str4 = "Default";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
std::string str1,str2,str3,str4;
str1 = str2 = str3 = str4 = "Default";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string str1 = "Default", str2 = "Default", str3 = "Default", str4 = "Default";
```

Initialize each variable separately, preferably declaring one variable per line.

Answer (score -1):

Method using some C++11 features:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm> //for_each
#include <iterator> //begin, end

using std::string;

int main() {

    string strs[4];
    std::for_each (std::begin(strs), std::end(strs), [](string &str) {
        str = "Default";
    });

    for (string str: strs)
        std::cout << str << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

One of the most significant aspects of this code is the lambda function. I had just read about them and had to try it out. Here is a link if you are [interested in learning more](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html)