# Converting ascii hex string to byte array

Tags: c, gcc

I have a char array say `char value []={'0','2','0','c','0','3'};`

I want to convert this into a byte array like `unsigned char val[]={'02','0c','03'}`

This is in an embedded application so i can't use string.h functions. How can i do this?

Comment: First of all, if you want the characters to be combined into byte-values, you can't have the destination with multi-character literals.

Comment: Did you mean `unsigned short val[]={0x02,0x0c,0x03}`?

Comment: @Marian Yes i exactly want it like this but unsigned char can also hold 0x02 etc right

Comment: @ganeshredcobra: `char`, `signed char` and `unsigned char` all of them can hold _0x02_ since it's just 2.

Comment: @ganeshredcobra So to be clear, you receive [nibbles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nibble) as hexadecimal digit characters, and you want to combine each pair into one byte? How do you know the length, is it always 6 chars == 3 bytes?

Comment: I think you're confusing people by the data type for your destination array. Most answers assume, that you want to do put always two numbers together AS A STRING, since your destination type is also `char`. I think you should make clear if you want to the final data in characte or in integer form.

Comment: If this turns out to *not* be each character representing a nibble in a byte (therefore 2 per output byte) i'll be surprised.

Comment: @hyde from the comments below, length is variable but up to 8 or 10, presumably always even.

Comment: This is a simple hex to binary conversion.  You should be able to code one in your sleep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sicne you talk about an embedded application I assume that you want to save the numbers as values and not as strings/characters. So if you just want to store your character data as numbers (for example in an integer), you can use [sscanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sscanf/).

This means you could do something like this:

```
 char source_val[] = {'0','A','0','3','B','7'} // Represents the numbers 0x0A, 0x03 and 0xB7
 uint8 dest_val[3];                            // We want to save 3 numbers
 for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
 {
     sscanf(&source_val[i*2],"%x%x",&dest_val[i]); // Everytime we read two chars --> %x%x
 }
 // Now dest_val contains 0x0A, 0x03 and 0xB7
```

However if you want to store it as a string (like in your example), you can't use `unsigned char` 
since this type is also just 8-Bit long, which means it can only store **one** character. Displaying 'B3' in a single (unsigned) char does not work.

**edit:** Ok according to comments, the goal is to save the passed data as a numerical value. Unfortunately the compiler from the opener does not support `sscanf` which would be the easiest way to do so. Anyhow, since this is (in my opinion) the simplest approach, I will leave this part of the answer at it is and try to add a more custom approach in this edit.

Regarding the data type, it actually doesn't matter if you have `uint8`. Even though I would advise to use some kind of integer data type, you can also store your data into an `unsigned char`. The problem here is, that the data you get passed, is a character/letter, that you want to interpret as a numerical value. However, the internal storage of your character differs. You can check the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/), where you can check the internal values for every character.
For example:

```
char letter = 'A'; // Internally 0x41 
char number = 0x61; // Internally 0x64 - represents the letter 'a'
```

As you can see there is also a differnce between upper an lower case.

If you do something like this:

```
int myVal = letter;  //
```

myVal **won't** represent the value 0xA (decimal 10), it will have the value 0x41.

The fact you can't use `sscanf` means you need a custom function. So first of all we need a way to conver **one** letter into an integer:

```
int charToInt(char letter)
{
    int myNumerical;
    // First we want to check if its 0-9, A-F, or a-f) --> See ASCII Table
    if(letter > 47 && letter < 58)
    {
        // 0-9
        myNumerical = letter-48;
        // The Letter "0" is in the ASCII table at position 48 -> meaning if we subtract 48 we get 0 and so on...
    }
    else if(letter > 64 && letter < 71)
    {
       // A-F
       myNumerical = letter-55 
       // The Letter "A" (dec 10) is at Pos 65 --> 65-55 = 10 and so on..
    }
    else if(letter > 96 && letter < 103)
    {
       // a-f
       myNumerical = letter-87
       // The Letter "a" (dec 10) is at Pos 97--> 97-87 = 10 and so on...
    }
    else
    {
       // Not supported letter...
       myNumerical = -1;
    }
    return myNumerical;
}
```

Now we have a way to convert every single character into a number. The other problem, is to always append two characters together, but this is rather easy:

```
int appendNumbers(int higherNibble, int lowerNibble)
{
     int myNumber = higherNibble << 4;
     myNumber |= lowerNibbler;
     return myNumber;
    // Example: higherNibble = 0x0A, lowerNibble = 0x03;  -> myNumber 0 0xA3
    // Of course you have to ensure that the parameters are not bigger than 0x0F 
}
```

Now everything together would be something like this:

```
 char source_val[] = {'0','A','0','3','B','7'} // Represents the numbers 0x0A, 0x03 and 0xB7
 int dest_val[3];                             // We want to save 3 numbers
 int temp_low, temp_high;
 for(int i = 0; i<3; i++)
 {
     temp_high = charToInt(source_val[i*2]);
     temp_low = charToInt(source_val[i*2+1]);
     dest_val[i] = appendNumbers(temp_high , temp_low);
 }
```

I hope that I understood your problem right, and this helps..

Comment: sscanf wis not available in compiler also uint8

Comment: Ok...could you please clarify if you want to save the data you receive as a literal (for example `string myNumber = "0xAB"`) - or do you want to save it numerical (for example `int myNumber = 0xAB`) ? Because there is a huge difference. The string would save 4 letters 0,x,A,B where as the integer (or any other numerical type) would save it as AB -> 171 decimal

Comment: i want as int myNumber = 0xAB

Comment: Ok, I guess I understood your problem now (at least I hope so)...just check the edit and let me know if it helped

Comment: yes it helped a lot but the code has issues when the values are FF or AA AB etc its not giving corect values always

Comment: Gonna look into it after lunch

Comment: What is the method for reverse conversion in an array its hex values convert it to char or ascii values

Comment: The reverse action should be done the same way around. You have your integer, then you split it up into two numericals (0xA3 in A/10 and 3). Then you convert them to their equivalent char (see ASCII table):

Answer (score 3):

If you have a "proper" array, like `value` as declared in the question, then you loop over the size of it to get each character. If you're on a system which uses the [ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) alphabet (which is most likely) then you can convert a hexadecimal digit in character form to a decimal value by subtracting `'0'` for digits (see the linked ASCII table to understand why), and subtracting `'A'` or `'a'` for letters (make sure no letters are higher than `'F'` of course) and add ten.

When you have the value from the first hexadeximal digit, then convert the second hexadecimal digit the same way. Multiply the first value by 16 and add the second value. You now have single byte value corresponding to two hexadecimal digits in character form.

---

Time for some code examples:

```
/* Function which converts a hexadecimal digit character to its integer value */
int hex_to_val(const char ch)
{
    if (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9')
        return ch - '0';  /* Simple ASCII arithmetic */
    else if (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'f')
        return 10 + ch - 'a';  /* Because hex-digit a is ten */
    else if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'F')
        return 10 + ch - 'A';  /* Because hex-digit A is ten */
    else
        return -1;  /* Not a valid hexadecimal digit */
}

...

/* Source character array */
char value []={'0','2','0','c','0','3'};

/* Destination "byte" array */
char val[3];

/* `i < sizeof(value)` works because `sizeof(char)` is always 1 */
/* `i += 2` because there is two digits per value */
/* NOTE: This loop can only handle an array of even number of entries */
for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < sizeof(value); i += 2, ++j)
{
    int digit1 = hex_to_val(value[i]);      /* Get value of first digit */
    int digit2 = hex_to_val(value[i + 1]);  /* Get value of second digit */

    if (digit1 == -1 || digit2 == -1)
        continue;  /* Not a valid hexadecimal digit */

    /* The first digit is multiplied with the base */
    /* Cast to the destination type */
    val[j] = (char) (digit1 * 16 + digit2);
}

for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    printf("Hex value %lu = %02x\n", i + 1, val[i]);
```

The output from the code above is

```
Hex value 1 = 02
Hex value 2 = 0c
Hex value 3 = 03
```

---

A note about the ASCII arithmetic: The ASCII value for the character `'0'` is `48`, and the ASCII value for the character `'1'` is `49`. Therefore `'1' - '0'` will result in `1`.

Comment: I like your approach, it actually feels a bit more slim than mine. But I would change the return value from `hex_to_val` to `-1` for an invalid char, because `0` can also be a valid return value. So there is no way to distinguish if the character was actually `0` or invalid!

Comment: @Toby I was thinking about that too, don't really know why I didn't do it. Updated it now though. Thanks for the remainder.

Answer (score 2):

It's easy with strtol():

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

void parse_bytes(unsigned char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    /** size 3 is important to make sure tmp is \0-terminated and
        the initialization guarantees that the array is filled with zeros */
    char tmp[3] = "";

    while (n--) {
        tmp[0] = *src++;
        tmp[1] = *src++;
        *dest++ = strtol(tmp, NULL, 16);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    unsigned char d[3];
    parse_bytes(d, "0a1bca", 3);
    assert(d[0] == 0x0a);
    assert(d[1] == 0x1b);
    assert(d[2] == 0xca);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If that is not available (even though it is NOT from string.h), you could do something like:

```
int ctohex(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
        return c - '0';
    }
    switch (c) {
        case 'a':
        case 'A':
            return 0xa;

        case 'b':
        case 'B':
            return 0xb;

        /**
         * and so on
         */
    }
    return -1;
}

void parse_bytes(unsigned char *dest, const char *src, size_t n)
{
    while (n--) {
        *dest = ctohex(*src++) * 16;
        *dest++ += ctohex(*src++);
    }
}
```

Comment: cant use string.h anyway in that device

Comment: @luserdroog When you initialize fixed size array (or struct), and leave part of it uninitialized, then that part will be initialized to zeros. More for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value).

Comment: @ganeshredcobra strtol is from stdlib.h, nevertheless I also edited the post to include an alternative witthout it.

Comment: @rmartinjak working on microcontroller it doesnt use stdlib.h also

Comment: @hyde and martinjak. I stand corrected. c89.3.5.7: "   If there are fewer initializers in a list than there are members of
an aggregate, the remainder of the aggregate shall be initialized
implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration." and "If an object that has static storage duration is not initialized
explicitly, it is initialized implicitly as if every member that has
arithmetic type were assigned 0 and every member that has pointer type
were assigned a null pointer constant."

Comment: @ganeshredcobra the second code block shows an alternative without strtol. The switch table is a bit lengthy, but it doesn't make any assumptions about the character set. If you're sure the letters are contiguous in your target platform's character set, you can use arithmetic instead. You also may or may not want to add proper error checking.

Answer (score 1):

<del>Assuming 8-bit bytes (not actually guaranteed by the C standard, but ubiquitous), the range of `unsigned char` is 0..255, and the range of `signed char` is -128..127. ASCII was developed as a 7-bit code using values in the range 0-127, so the same value can be represented by both `char` types.</del>

---

For the now discovered task of converting a counted hex-string from ascii to unsigned bytes, here's my take:

```
unsigned int atob(char a){
    register int b;
    b = a - '0';    // subtract '0' so '0' goes to 0 .. '9' goes to 9
    if (b > 9) b = b - ('A' - '0') + 10;  // too high! try 'A'..'F'
    if (b > 15) b = b - ('a' - 'A);  // too high! try 'a'..'f'
    return b;
}

void myfunc(const char *in, int n){
    int i;
    unsigned char *ba;
    ba=malloc(n/2);
    for (i=0; i < n; i+=2){
        ba[i/2] = (atob(in[i]) << 4) | atob(in[i+1]);
    }
    // ... do something with ba
}
```

Comment: Am getting this array as an char array char value []={'0','2','0','c','0','3'}; How will i convert it to the array you mentioned its not clear?

Comment: Expanded the answer a little. Not entirely sure what you need.

Comment: Am receiving the data as char array from UART of a microcontroller i want convert it to a byte array that val[0] must be MSB and val[1] must be LSB .Like this i want to convert the whole char array to byte array.

Comment: `char` and `byte` are the same thing. Are these pieces of larger (multi-byte) values?

Comment: Nope its not part of large value the length of the array which i receive will be max 8 or 10. I want to merge val[0] and val[1] How can i do that by bit shifting or something like that?I Think the value am getting in char array is ascii value.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add this (and more) information? What do you mean by wanting to "merge" the two values? If val[0] is the MSB and val[1] the LSB of a 16-bit (2-byte) unsigned integer (`unsigned short`), then you can re-form the integer with `(val[0]<<8)|val[1]` or `(unsigned)val[0]*256+val[1]`.

Comment: I think the problem is, that he gets the data as `char` , maybe over some kind of protocol/interface (so he has no influence on how he gets the data). Meaning this if he gets the actualy value 0x3B he will get two characters containing '3' and 'B'. If he just passes/copies this, he won't get 3B in his destination value, since these characters are internally displayed with ASCII.

Comment: @luserdroog I believe they're supposed to represent nibbles of a byte, not bytes of a 16-bit word. i.e. `02` represents a *byte* `00000010`. may be wrong on that, but I don't think so.

Comment: Took some effort to tease that out, but yes. Then I thought I should leave the answer just so these comments would remain for others. Finally, I guess I have to write the damned function! :)

Comment: @luserdroog tease what out of me? I just got here =P

Comment: No, I meant "tease out [the goal from the question]".

Comment: +1 for your atob function. But why is b `unsigned char` and not for ex. `register int`?