# How to quickly clear DWORD pointer array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is my code.

```
DWORD *dwDSE = new DWORD[4096];
```

Here is my [inefficient] way of clearing it:

```
for (INT k=0;k<4096;k++)
    dwDSE[k] = 0;
```

What is the best way to clear it/initialize it to zeros?

Comment: What makes you think that's inefficient?

Comment: `memset(dwDSE,0,4096);`

Comment: `std::vector<DWORD> dwDSE (4096)` will be efficiently zeroed (or set to any other value you want). Plus, no need to `delete` it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C/C++ initialization of a normal array with one default value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/c-c-initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)

Comment: @delnan, I just thought it was compared to possibly a more efficient, optimized, function.

Comment: @JeffR The more information you give the compiler, the better it can optimize.  Your loop gives maximum information, as does using `std::fill_n` or an `std::vector` (because the compiler will know the actual type involved in the loop).  A function like `memset` can't do as well, because all it sees is bytes.

Comment: @SJD; No. That's not the dupe.

Comment: Modern LLVM will actually detect the idiom in the `for` loop and replace it with a `memset` call, as I've found before to my surprise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [memset](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memset):

```
memset(dwDSE,0,4096*sizeof(DWORD));
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `4096*sizeof(DWORD)`? You're just clearing the first 4096 bytes, not the first 4096 elements.

Comment: @slugonamission it is enough to say `sizeof(DWORD)` because you already set the size at declaration. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset

Comment: @slugonamission: std::memset and memset are same?

Comment: @SJD: I'm more familiar with C than C++, but I'm pretty sure `OBJ *obj = new OBJ[xxx]` is different than `OBJ obj[xxx];`  That is, OP is making an array of DWORD....

Comment: @Anil8753 "std" a namespace. The "::" operator is the "scope" operator. It tells the compiler which class/namespace to look in for an identifier. So, `memset` is in `std` namespace.

Comment: @cegfault The OP is dynamically allocating an array (which you should never do in C++).  You're right, however, that depending on the context, `DWORD dwDSE[4096];` might be more appropriate.

Comment: @SJD - that would only clear the first element, since `sizeof(DWORD)` is 4 bytes. If it was an array, `sizeof(dwDSE)` would work, but it's a simple pointer in this case.

Answer (score 6):

You can initialized it to zero as

```
DWORD *dwDSE = new DWORD[4096](); //Note the empty parenthesis ()
```

Answer (score 2):

Unless you've got a really bad compiler, the most efficient way
of clearing it should be:

```
std::fill_n( dwDSI, 4096, 0 );
```

This should generate about the same code as your loop (which is
also very efficient), and in many cases, will be significantly
more efficient than `memset`, which is normally the worst
solution (and of course, only works for the special value of 0).

Of course, you wouldn't normally ever do a `new DWORD[4096]`
anyway.  If you write:

```
std::vector<DWORD> dwDSI( 4096 );
```

you'll get it already initialized to 0, and you won't leak it in
case of an exception.  If you need it for a legacy interface
(about the only reason one would use `DWORD` anyway), you can
get the raw pointer with `&dwDSI[0]`, or `dwDSI.data()` if you
have C++11.

EDIT:

A comment to another answer makes me realize an essential point:
do you really have to allocate the array dynamically?  If not,

```
DWORD dwDSI[4096] = {};
```

is the best solution.  (The `= {}` ensures initialization with
0.)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2012, so is that compatible with C++11 you reference? And, if I use the vector declaration, how do I reference individual elements?

Comment: @JeffR Partially.  I think it does have the `data` member; try it, and if not, use `&dwDSI[0]`.  As for referencing the individual elements: `dwDSI[index]` works perfectly; if you're referencing them sequentially, you can also use the iterators.

Comment: I do not want to put it on the stack, that is why I am allocating it as **new**.

Comment: @JeffR I don't know why you wouldn't want it on the stack, but `std::vector` won't put it on the stack, so you're safe there.  (In generally, you should avoid dynamic allocation whenever possible.)

Comment: why would I want to avoid dynamic allocation?

Comment: @JeffR It's extra complication, and throws in a few additional things that can go wrong (like memory leaks).  If one of the built-in lifetimes is appropriate, let the compiler take care of managing it.

Answer (score 1):

The [memset](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset) function can be used in this case.

```
std::memset(dwDSE, 0, sizeof(dwDSE)*4096);
```

Or [fill_n](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill) function:

```
std::fill_n(dwDSE, 4096, 0);
```

Comment: But in std::memset, sizeof(dwDSE) is only 8. Is that enough?

Comment: @JeffR: no, you need to do `sizeof(DWORD)*4096`.

Comment: @JeffR it really repends on what type DWORD is. If we take `int a[100]` then `sizeof(a)` is (in my case int is 4 bytes) => 100*4 bytes

Comment: @SJD, shouldn't your memset above have sizeof(dwDSE)*4096?

Comment: @JeffR - no, `sizeof(dwDSE)` takes the size of the pointer in this case (since `dwDSE` is a `DWORD*` in this case), hence it needs to be `sizeof(DWORD)`.