# Array ints not returning correctly

Tags: c++, arrays

I have an array I am trying to declare with all it's cells equal to 0. Everytime I try to access any of the cells, except the first, they always return with -858993460, which is definitely not 0.

Here is the declaration of the array:

```
int values[8] = { };
```

Here is the array cell being printed, which prints out -858993460.

```
cout << value.values[1];
```

This line works fine, though:

```
cout << value.values[0];
```

The exact Declaration of the value object (Value is a class):

`Value value;`

The Declaration of the Value class:

```
#pragma once
class Value{
    public:
    int values[8] = { };
    Value();
    ~Value();
};
```

Only the first cell prints 0, So how can I declare an array with all cells being 0?

For any additional information, here is enough code to reproduce the problem (combine this with the declaration of `Value`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Value.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char null;
    Value value;
    cout << value.values[1];
    cin >> null; //this just holds up the program so I have time to read what it printed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [MCVE] please as usual!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value

Comment: `^` is the bitwise xor operator; `2^3 == 1`.

Comment: As  @KeithThompson said, you just declared an array with 1 element, so `int values[(2 ^ 3)] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };` will be wrong.

Comment: @user: For an aggregate initializer like `{ }`, unspecified values are initialized to zero.

Comment: @Keith Thompson thanks for pointing this out

Comment: I have fixed and edited all the mistakes with the `^` operator, but this only solved the issue for the first cell.

Comment: @WilliamThomas: Your edit invalided my answer to your original question. It also doesn't provide nearly enough information. You tell us `Value` is a class, but you've told us nothing about the class. Is your declaration `int values[8] = { };` inside the class definition? You need to show us an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (read that link!). I should be able to copy-and-paste the code from your question, compile and run it on my system, and reproduce the problem you're having.

Comment: @KeithThompson Done. There is also the cpp file, but that is empty besides the constructor and deconstructor, which both are empty, but I can still show the file if you want.

Comment: As for the `2^3` error, did you correct that in your program and then recompile and re-run the program to confirm that the problem is still there, or did you just edit the question?

Comment: @KeithThompson I compiled and ran it, works for only the first cell, `values[0]`.

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve again. You've shown us several isolated snippets of code, not a program that we can try ourselves. The program I just tried based on your snippets works correctly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122019/discussion-between-william-thomas-and-keith-thompson).

Answer (score 3):

```
int values[(2 ^ 3)] = { };
std::cout << values[0];
```

produces 0 as you would expect. `value.values` is some other value that you didn't show.

`2 ^ 3` equals `1`, you probably meant a version of `pow`. This explains why you get

> too many initializer variables

when you use `int values[(2 ^ 3)] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };`, because `values` only has 1 element.

`int values[8] = {};` will properly initialize all 8 values with `0`.

Comment: `pow()` is a floating-point function, and its result is neither constant nor an integer, so it can't be used as an array dimension. `1<<3` (or just `8`) would work.

Comment: Okay, I forgot about c++ not having an exponential function, but your solution only fixes the first cell. `cout << value.values[1];` still prints -858993460. And `values` is a global variable of `value`, which explains `value.values`.

Comment: @WilliamThomas You should edit the exact declaration of `value.values` into your question so we can check why `value.values[1]` is garbage.

Comment: @nwp Done, but it was a pretty simple line, I could provide any more information if you need it.

Comment: @WilliamThomas That doesn't help much without knowing the declaration of `Value`.

Comment: @nwp Done, just look at Keith Thompson's comments for any additional information on the class.

Comment: I cannot supply any more information on the class, and the OP has failed to do so.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be assuming that `^` is an exponentiation operator. It isn't; C++ has no exponentiation operator. `^` is bitwise xor, so `2^3 == 1`. If you try to access elements with indices greater than `0`, you'll get garbage (actually undefined behavior, but a garbage value is a common symptom).

You could use `1 << 3`, which yields `8` -- or you could just use `8`.

This  should  work if you're defining a standalone object:

```
int values[8] = { };
```

But if `values` is actually a member of a struct or class (as implied by your use of `value.values[0]`), it's a different story. If you want information on that, please update the question to show the declaration of `values` in its correct context.

Comment: Updated, I do need more information on the declaration of a global array.

Comment: Your update invalidated my answer, which was to the question you originally asked.