# How to Initialize an array using initializer-list C++

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization

I have a question related to C++ arrays and structs.  I have a struct:

```
struct npc_next_best_spot{
    npc_next_best_spot(): x({0}),
                          y({0}),
                          value(-1),
                          k(0),
                          i({0}), 
                          triple_ress({0}),
                          triple_number({0}),
                          bigI(0)
    {}

    int x[3]; 
    int y[3]; 
    double value; 
    int k; 
    int i[3]; 
    int triple_ress[3]; 
    int triple_number[3];
    int bigI;
};
```

but this gives the warning

> "list-initializer for non-class type must not be parenthesized".

So how can I make sure that these arrays are initialized with `0` values for all?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do as the error suggests.  You can use a brace initializer for your arrays like

```
npc_next_best_spot() : x{}, y{}, value(-1), k(0), i{}, triple_ress{}, triple_number{}, bigI(0) {}
```

Leaving the list blanks works as any missing initializer will zero initialize the element in the array.

Comment: So how could I init any array with -1 for example?

Comment: @Adrian All -1 or just the first element?

Comment: lets say all 0 but all values for i should be -1

Comment: @Adrian If you want them to be a value other than 0 you need to specify it like `: x{-1, -2, -3} ...` or do the assignment in the constructor body.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish that by not using the parens at all:

```
struct npc_next_best_spot{
    npc_next_best_spot(): x{0},
                          y{0},
                          value(-1),
                          k(0),
                          i({0}), 
                          triple_ress({0}),
                          triple_number({0}),
                          bigI(0)
    {}
```

Since you are using the uniform initializer it is worth to note that you can initialize to zero an array in multiple ways using a list-initializer:

```
    int a[3] = {0}; // valid C and C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
    int a[3] = {}; // invalid C but valid C++ way to zero-out a block-scope array
```

Note that the previous syntax does not work if you want to set the array to a value `c!=0`.

`int a[3] = {-1}` would mean set the first element of `a` to `-1` (just the first one). As another example, `int a[5] = { 1, 2 };` will result in `1,2,0,0,0`

C++ has a nice set of function for inizialiting containers and something like the following will do the job:

```
std::fill_n(a, 3, -1);
```

If your compiler is GCC and you are working in `c99` you can also use the following syntax: `int a[1024] = {[0 ... 1023] = 5};` to initialize a portion of the array to a value (even though this lead to an increase in the generated code size proportional to the size of the initialized array).

- [Check an exmaple online here](http://ideone.com/f3Yb5l)
- [More on this here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Designated-Inits.html).

[I strongly suggest to take a look at this page on *array initialization*.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization)

and [this answer for further details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)