# Array initialization with identical elements

Tags: c++

Is there shortcut to initialize fixed size array with constants. For examle, it I need `int array[300]` with 10 in each of 300 spaces, is there trick to avoid writinig 10 300 times?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialization of a normal array with one default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-a-normal-array-with-one-default-value)

Comment: With `std::array`, you could implement something to have that array initialized that way, for C-array, simpler would be to fill it.

Comment: `std::vector<int> v(300,10);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a compile time solution that uses initialisation (uses `std::array` instead of a C array):

```
template<std::size_t N, typename T, std::size_t... Is>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_filled_array(
    std::index_sequence<Is...>,
    T const& value
)
{
    return {((void)Is, value)...};
}

template<std::size_t N, typename T>
constexpr std::array<T, N> make_filled_array(T const& value)
{
    return make_filled_array<N>(std::make_index_sequence<N>(), value);
}

auto xs = make_filled_array<300, int>(10);
auto ys = make_filled_array<300>(10);
```

Comment: You may reverse order of template parameter to allow `T` deduction.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`std::fill_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n):

```cpp
int array[300] = {0};        // initialise the array with all 0's
std::fill_n(array, 300, 10); // fill the array with 10's
```

Comment: Note, this doesn't *initialize* a fixed array, it fills via *assignment*.

Comment: It also isn’t `constexpr`, so you can’t use it at compile time to get the same effect.