# how is int lastIndex[NO_OF_CHARS]={-1}; different from vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS, -1);?

Tags: c++

how is the contents of

```
int lastIndex[NO_OF_CHARS]={-1};
```

different from the contents of

```
vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS, -1);
```

?

How I use it (copied from comments on @digital_hog's answer):

```
#define NO_OF_CHARS 256 

int longestUniqueSubsttr(string str) { 
  int n = str.size(); 
  int res = 0; 
  vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS,-1); // i want to replace this with array 
  
  int i = 0; 
  for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
    i = max(i, lastIndex[str[j]] + 1); 
    res = max(res, j - i + 1); lastIndex[str[j]] = j; 
  } 
  return res; 
} 

int main() { 
  int t;
  cin>>t;
  while(t--) {
    string s="";
    cin>>s;
    cout<<longestUniqueSubsttr(s)<<endl;
  } 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/1065800/3727050 - Your array syntax is only initialising the first value from what I see...

Answer (score 1):

```
int lastIndex[NO_OF_CHARS]={-1};
```

declares a static array of `NO_OF_CHARS` `int`'s where the first elements will be copied from the brace enclosed intializer list `{ -1 }` and all other elements will be default-initialized (to 0 in this case). So you end up with an array `[-1, 0, ..., 0]`

```
vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS, -1);
```

initializes a `std::vector<int>` (a dynamic array, if you want) with `NO_OF_CHARS` copies of the second parameter, e.g. `NO_OF_CHARS` times -1.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS, -1);
```

will make lastIndex look like {-1, -1, -1 ... } (NO_OF_CHARS times).

The normal static array will do the same, the difference is in the way the arrays are allocated.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way i can assign -1 to all index of the array too..

Comment: If you know NO_OF_CHARS, you could initialize it with int lastIndex[NO_OF_CHARS]={-1, -1, .....}; (NO_OF_CHARS entries in the aggregate). A more elegant way is to use a for loop and set every entry to -1.

Comment: i tried but they are giving different results.. NO_OF_CHARS=256

Comment: The for loop may look like this: for (int i = 0; i<NO_OF_CHARS; i++) {lastIndex[i] = -1;}

Comment: #define NO_OF_CHARS 256 
int longestUniqueSubsttr(string str) 
{ 
    int n = str.size(); 
    int res = 0; 
    vector<int> lastIndex(NO_OF_CHARS,-1);// i want to replace this with array 
    int i = 0; 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { 
        i = max(i, lastIndex[str[j]] + 1); 
          res = max(res, j - i + 1); 
        lastIndex[str[j]] = j; 
    } 
    return res; 
}  
int main() {
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
        string s="";
        cin>>s;
        cout<<longestUniqueSubsttr(s)<<endl;
    }
 return 0;
}

Comment: okay thank you.. but why does it work when i make int a[n] ={0} , then all n are assigned to 0

Comment: You are in fact right, int lastIndex[NO_OF_CHARS]={-1};  will set all entries of lastIndex to -1. Sorry for the mistake.