# Is there any way to set all elements of a matrix to 1 in C++?

Tags: c++, matrix

Say I am declaring a matrix like this--> long long int A[100][100]. Is there any way to assign the value 1 to all its elements at the time of declaring the matrix?

Comment: What is the type of this matrix? Please, provide the full declaration.

Comment: long long int A[100][100]

Comment: There were question like that before:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-all-elements-of-an-array-to-one-default-value-in-c

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fill_n method and initialize array like this:

`std::fill_n(&A[0][0], sizeof(A) / sizeof(**A), 1);`

Check [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) for more information about fill_na.

Hope it solves your question.

Comment: This is not correct. It's undefined behavior to treat a 2d array as a contiguous chunk of memory.

Comment: So do you have any other alternative?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to assign the value 1 to all its elements at the time of declaring the matrix?

I interpret that as you want something `constexpr` and I'd use `std::array` instead of plain arrays since `std::array`s are easier to work with.

I've made templates for `make_array` that creates a 1 dimensional array and templates for `make_2d_array` that creates a 2 dimensional array, using the first set of templates.

The goal of the templates is that if we for example want a 2d array with 2 rows and 3 columns of `int` with all `int`s initialized with `1`, this should be created:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> A{{
    {1, 1, 1},
    {1, 1, 1}
}};
```

In the code below `make_array<int, 3, 1>()` will create the inner arrays, `std::array<int, 3>{1, 1, 1}`, and `make_2d_array<int, 2, 3, 1>()` will be equivalent to:

```
std::array<std::array<int, 3>, 2> A{
    make_array<int, 3, 1>(),         // std::array<int, 3>{1, 1, 1}
    make_array<int, 3, 1>()          // std::array<int, 3>{1, 1, 1}
};
```

These are a set of templates that can accomplish that:

```
#include <array>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

//-------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T, T init, std::size_t... X>
constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(X)>
make_array(std::index_sequence<X...>) {
    //
    //        used for folding only then discarded below
    //                                          |
    return std::array<T, sizeof...(X)>{ ((void)(X), (init))... };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t X, T init = T{}>
constexpr std::array<T, X> make_array() {
    return make_array<T, init>(std::make_index_sequence<X>{});
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------
template <typename T, T init, std::size_t X, std::size_t... Y>
constexpr std::array< std::array<T, X>, sizeof...(Y)>
make_2d_array(std::index_sequence<Y...>) {
    return std::array< std::array<T, X>, sizeof...(Y)>{
        //
        //      Y used for folding only and discarded
        //      |
        ((void)(Y), make_array<T, X, init>())... 
    };
}

template <typename T, std::size_t Y, std::size_t X, T init = T{}>
constexpr std::array<std::array<T, X>, Y>
make_2d_array() {
    return make_2d_array<T, init, X>(std::make_index_sequence<Y>{});
}
```

It can then be used like this:

```
constexpr auto A = make_2d_array<int, 2, 3, 1>(); // Y=2, X=3, init value 1
```

[Full demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7MK9Td)
(click on the ***Cppinsights*** link top left in the demo if you'd like to see how the folding unfolds)

Comment: Since C++20 we could take advantage of `consteval` and `std::fill_n` beeing `constexpr`: https://godbolt.org/z/a6YGhs . Do you think that folding expressions and `index_sequence` have some advantages in terms of compilation time or generated code?

Comment: @Bob__ Oh, that's a nice C++20 addition! I expect folding and `index_sequence`s to make compilation a bit slower. If the same dimensions are used throughout the program I don't think it'll be noticeable - but if one uses a large number of different dimensions it may be noticeable. It's not recursive so the number of instances will still be reasonably low (4 per unique Y,X combination used). I usually care more about runtime and try to not rebuild parts not affected by recent changes. I hope the answer appeals to people with a similar mindset, as well as OP who asked for it (as I understood it)

Comment: Btw, I suggest you add your code as an answer. It's much simpler than mine and if OP can use C++20 - it'd be a done deal.

Comment: Well, that's a big [if](https://godbolt.org/z/zPnYEq).

Comment: @Bob__ I'll try it on my MSVC installation, brb.... Edit: Nope, not even there :-( ... still, it'd be a good answer (I'd vote for it) and it'll probably work in MSVC soon anyway. clang++ trunk compiles it fine btw.

Answer (score 1):

As shown in Ted Lyngmo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064281/4944425), instead of a `long long int A[100][100]` we can declare and initialize a `std::array<std::array<long long, 100>, 100>` using a `constexpr` function.

Since C++20, it's possible to declare a function with a [`consteval`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) specifier which

> specifies that a function is an *immediate function*, that is, every call to the function must produce a compile-time constant.

Moreover, the algorithm [`std::fill_n`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/fill_n) has been made `constexpr`.

So that we can write the following two function templates:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>

template <class Type, std::size_t Size>
consteval auto make_1d_array(Type value)
{
    std::array<Type, Size> result;
    std::fill_n(result.begin(), Size, value);
    return result;
}

template <class Type, std::size_t Rows, std::size_t Cols>
consteval auto make_2d_array(Type value)
{
    std::array<std::array<Type, Cols>, Rows> result;
    std::fill_n( result.begin(), Rows
               , make_1d_array<Type, Cols>(value) );
    return result;
}
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/osrcE4).