# set class object array init value at definition of object array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I have two questions. I run the below code and it sets each array object variable to 20 ın `GCC 6.3 version.` However, when I try the higher version of GCC, It gives an error.
**Why is there this changing?**

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    int a;
    public:
    A(int);
};

A::A(int init_val){
    this -> a = init_val;
}

int main(){
    A a[10](20);
}
```

Actually, I want to set an array which has more parameters for a constructor like that:

```
A(int, char);
A a[10](20, 'A');
```

The final version of the code is below.
This gives an error in every version of gcc.

**Is there any way to set an array object like that?**

```
#include <iostream>
class A{
    int a;
    char b;
    public:
    A(int, char);
};

A::A(int init_val, char init_ch ){
    this -> a = init_val;
    this -> b = init_ch;
}

int main(){
    A a[10](20, 'A');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to initialise an array like that in C++. Neither of your attempts are well-formed.

You can initialise every element explicitly like this:

```
A a[10]{
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
    {20, 'A'},
};
```

*If* the element type were default constructible (which your class is *not*) and copy assignable (which your class is), then you could work around the inability by default initialising, and assigning the elements later. For example:

```
A a[10];
std::fill_n(a, std::size(a), A{20, 'A'});
```

Comment: Without default ctor, that is correct. If you can add one, you could use `std::fill_n(a, 10, A{20, 'A'});` for a somewhat nicer syntax. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-all-elements-of-an-array-to-one-default-value-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

If the initializers are actual compile time constant values, you can just add a default ctor:

```
class A {
    ...
    A(): a(20) {}
}
```

But I know no clean way in the general case.There is a possible workaround if you can use dynamic objects: use a vector and `emplace_back` the objects. At the end, the vector will contain an array of objects:

```
va = std::vector<A>;
va.reserve(10)
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
   va.emplace_back(20, 'a');
}
A *a = va.data();              // you now have a array of 10 A objects
```

You simply have to make the *backing* vector last as long as you need the array to exist...