# Intialize the whole array with int 1

Tags: c++, arrays

I found the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-all-elements-of-an-array-to-one-default-value-in-c) but it is for GCC compiler and I am using clang.
I want to intialize the whole array with integer 1(C++ std=17).

```
std::cout<<a[5] ; // I want it to print 1
```

Comment: I have intialized  int a[100];

Comment: The `fill_n` approach works also with clang, it's part of the standard library, not a compiler extension.

Comment: *but it is for GCC compiler and I am using clang.* --  That makes no difference.  Any conforming C++ 11 compiler has `std::fill_n`.  That includes g++, clang, Visual C++, and any other compiler that purports to be standard.  Did you actually try the solution in the duplicate link, or just assumed it wouldn't work?

Comment: When picking tags for your question, please *read their description*. The [tag:compiler-construction] tag, for example, explicitly explains that it shouldn’t be used here.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Pretty sure they were talking about the GCC designated initialisers extension that lets you write `int x[10] = {[0...9] = 1};`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, but the link in the post clearly has `std::fill_n` as the top rated answer.  Why the OP would skip over that answer is a mystery.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Yes I can use std::fill_n  but I have to do it without using any stl other than <iostream>  , is there any similar way like designated intialisation to do this ?

Comment: @TJSM -- You should state up front what you cannot use.  You posted a link that has `std::fill_n` as the top answer, yet you didn't mention anything about it, which was confusing as to why you skipped over it.  Last, your post has `C++ std=17` mentioned -- if that is the case, why are you not simply using the facilities offered by C++17?  Those facilities being `std::fill`, and `std::fill_n`.