# how to initialize a single value to whole array in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, c++17, list-initialization

I'm trying to initialize a single value to whole array in c++.
For ex:- I want to initialize 1 in whole array by writing it by only once

I have tried to initializing 1 in whole array but it throws error , I'm expecting 1 in whole array.

ex- int array[5]={0};
output- 0 0 0 0 0

int array[5]={1};
output- 1 0 0 0 0
expecting- 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: You'll have to repeat that '1' 5 times.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1065774/initialization-of-all-elements-of-an-array-to-one-default-value-in-c I think this will answer your question

Comment: Use std::fill_n(array, 5, 1);

Answer (score -1):

if you want 1 value at very index you can do this by

```
int arr[5] = {1,1,1,1,1}; or 
int arr[5];
arr[0] = 1;
arr[1] = 1;
arr[2] = 1;
arr[3] = 1;
arr[4] = 1;
```

otherwise if you write arr[5] = {1}; only first index will have value 1 rest will be assigned zero automatically like this {1,0,0,0,0}

```
or #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    memset(arr, 1, sizeof(arr));
    cout << arr;
    return 0;
}
```

so type this code this memset function will fill all the index with value 1 by writing it only once.

hope this answer helps you.
Edited, try this code snippet working perfectly fine

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

int main () {
  std::array<int,5> myarray;

  myarray.fill(1);

  std::cout << "myarray contains:";
  for ( int& x : myarray) { std::cout << ' ' << x; }

  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: But that `memset` doesn't do that. It will most likely fill the array with 16843009's (1010101 in hexadecimal).

Comment: You may want to review the documentation of [`std::memset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memset). Besides, what do you think `cout << arr;` does?

Comment: try this code snippet above which i recently edited

Comment: Look up `std::fill`, as it will work with a standard array as well as `std::vector`.